# Python - Write Values from Dictionary into .csv according to keys representing the position of column and row (coordinates)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am having a dictionary where the keys represents a coordinate (column,row) of a specific value:

```
d={(1,1) : value_1 , (1,2) : value_2 , (2,1) : value_3 , (2,2) : value_4}
```

The csv-file should only contain the values, but at the right position defined by the keys (column,row):

```
value_1 , value_3
value_2 , value_4
```

I hope anybody can give me a hint, how i could handle this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay using Pandas, you could use the key coordinates to directly add the dictionary values to their appropriate location, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    (1,1): 1,
    (1,2): 2,
    (2,1): 3,
    (2,2): 4
    }

df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in d.items():
    df.at[k[1], k[0]] = v

df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Which would output the following data table as `out.csv`:

```
1.0,3.0
2.0,4.0
```

Comment: Starting it with CMD or Powershell using Win10 that worked as intended. But running it by starting the script with doubleclick, i ran into a permission denied Error. The solution was, to change 'out.csv' in df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False) into the full path where the script is located.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Python's built in csv module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

All you need to do is:

```
import csv

def output_csv(input_dict, output_filename):
    # translate original data dict into a list of dictionaries representing each row
    output_list = []
    for coord, value in input_dict.items():
        while coord[1] > len(output_list):
            # insert rows if the required row is not there
            output_list.append({})
        output_list[coord[1]-1][coord[0]] = value
    
    # obtain the column field names
    csv_fields = []
    for row in output_list:
        # check each row to make sure we have all the columns
        if len(csv_fields) < len(row):
            csv_fields = list(row)
    # sort the fields in order
    csv_fields.sort()
    
    # open the output file for writing
    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        # init the csv DictWriter
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,csv_fields, extrasaction='ignore',dialect='excel')
        # write each row
        for row in output_list:
            writer.writerow(row)

d={(1,1) : 'value_1' , (1,2) : 'value_2' , (2,1) : 'value_3' , (2,2) : 'value_4'}
d2={(1,2) : 'value_2' , (2,1) : 'value_3' , (2,2) : 'value_4'}
d3={(1,3) : 'value_1' , (1,2) : 'value_2' , (2,1) : 'value_3' , (2,2) : 'value_4'}

output_csv(d,  "output1.csv")
output_csv(d2, "output2.csv")
output_csv(d3, "output3.csv")
```

The outputs are:

`output1.csv`:

```
value_1,value_3
value_2,value_4
```

`output2.csv`:

```
,value_3
value_2,value_4
```

`output3.csv`:

```
,value_3
value_2,value_4
value_1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple approach that will solve your problem:

Say you have testread.csv with the following:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

what you may do is:

```
import csv

d={(1,1) : "a" , (1,2) : "b" , (2,1) : "c" , (2,2) : "d"}

#open the file you need to modify and create a list of all rows
f = open('testread.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
rowlist = list(reader)
f.close()

for (k,v) in zip(d.keys(),d.values()):
    rowlist[k[0]][k[1]]= v

#open the destination file and modify it
new_list = open('testwrite.csv', 'w', newline = '')
csv_writer = csv.writer(new_list)
csv_writer.writerows(rowlist)
new_list.close()
```

You will get the following contents for testwrite.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,a,b,4,5
1,c,d,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```